# probleming in generating corresponding string for a regex

Tags: regex, glibc

I have a program with regex as:

```
"\\s*(\\d{1,5})?\\s*(?:<(?<pri>\\d{1,3})>)"
```

I need to test the matching pattern thus I am trying a corresponding string which matches the expression.

can you provide an example of string that matches the above regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
23123<123>
 123  <1>
123  <123>
 123<12>
<123>
    <1>
```

Something of this sort.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/75

```
<space>(0 or more)<integer>(1 to 5 may or may not be there)<space>(0 or more)<(Symbol <)<integer>(1 to 3)>(symbol >)
```